# JupyterLabにて、Pathを通したい。

Tags: python

Pythonについて。

只今、JupyterLabを使ってPythonを学んでいます。
OSはwindows10です。

では、質問です。

JupyterLabにて、新たにPathを通す方法を教えてください。
しかし、なにかのモジュールを使う度、append()を使ってPathを通すのは煩雑です。
ただ、import 〇〇とするだけで、オリジナルのモジュールやプログラムを使いたいです。

環境変数にPYTHONPATHを入れるというのをどこかで見たのですが、
ユーザー環境変数にPYTHONPATHを入れて、変数値をオリジナルのものが入ったフォルダに設定し、importしても呼び出しができていないようです。

sys.pathを見てもフォルダは表示されていません。

どなたか、正しい方法をお教えください。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Jupyter Notebook に環境変数を設定する](https://kakakakakku.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/01/222035), [Pythonでモジュールパスを設定する](https://blue-red.ddo.jp/~ao/wiki/wiki.cgi?page=Python%A4%C7%A5%E2%A5%B8%A5%E5%A1%BC%A5%EB%A5%D1%A5%B9%A4%F2%C0%DF%C4%EA%A4%B9%A4%EB)

Comment: 見間違いでなければ、kunifさんには度々お世話になっているようです。コメントありがとうございます。解決出来ました。今までなぜ失敗していたのか分かりませんが先ほどやってみたら出来ました！ベストアンサーとしたいところですが、それができないため、このコメントとともに、回答への感謝とさせてくださいませ。

Comment: 私自身はJupyterLabを普段使っていないので、断言できなくて回答にしていません。解決のために使った方法を自己回答にされると良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

それでは改めまして。
kunif様、回答ありがとうございます。
教えられたサイトを参考にしつつ、JupyterLabやAnaconda Navigatorを再起動したことで、もしかしたらPathが適用されたのかなと思います。
別日に新しいPathを通して同じことをやってみると、やはりすんなりと事が運べたので、ようやく頭痛の種が1つ解消された心持ちがしております。